# Composer-Rest-Server is generating an additional id string in my concept

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have defined a concept in my model file. It looks like this

```
concept DoctorSchedule {
o Boolean AM12to1 optional
o Boolean AM1to2 optional
o Boolean AM2to3 optional
o Boolean AM3to4 optional
o Boolean AM4to5 optional
o Boolean AM5to6 optional
o Boolean AM6to7 optional
o Boolean AM7to8 optional
o Boolean AM8to9 optional
o Boolean AM9to10 optional
o Boolean AM10to11 optional
o Boolean AM11to12 optional
o Boolean PM12to1 optional 
}

participant Doctor identified by doctorID {
o String doctorID
o String contact 
o DoctorSchedule doctorSchedule

}
```

When I test it on the composer-playground, and try to add a new doctor participant. The JSON preview looks something like this

```
{
"$class": "org.acme.Doctor",
"doctorID": "0624",
"contact": "",
"doctorSchedule": {
"$class": "org.acme.DoctorSchedule",
"AM12to1": false,
"AM1to2": false,
"AM2to3": false,
"AM3to4": false,
"AM4to5": false,
"AM5to6": false,
"AM6to7": false,
"AM7to8": false,
"AM8to9": false,
"AM9to10": false,
"AM10to11": false,
"AM11to12": false,
"PM12to1": false,

}}
```

But when I generate the composer-rest-server and try to add a doctor using the post method, an additional id field appears

```
{
"$class": "org.acme.Doctor",
"doctorID": "stri1ng",
"contact": "string",
"doctorSchedule": {
"$class": "org.acme.DoctorSchedule",
"AM12to1": true,
"AM1to2": true,
"AM2to3": true,
"AM3to4": true,
"AM4to5": true,
"AM5to6": true,
"AM6to7": true,
"AM7to8": true,
"AM8to9": true,
"AM9to10": true,
"AM10to11": true,
"AM11to12": true,
"PM12to1": true,
"id": "string"
}}
```

What is this id field inside the DoctorSchedule concept? According to my understanding, you don't need an ID to identify a concept (like with assets or participants.) And why is this id field appearing in the composer-rest-server and not on the composer-playground?

Note: The post method throws an error if this id is a blank string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have found a bug in the REST server - I have added this new issue: [3963](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3963) whilst investigating your problem I also discovered a related problem and created a 2nd issue: [3962](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3962)

My experience differs from yours in that I can leave the extra id field empty - which you obviously can't do with the DoctorID.

Comment: I've seen your related issue, and I'd like to add that when using composer-playground. If a field is missing, the transaction goes through but the registry isn't updated. Shouldn't there be a way to leave some fields empty and still create or update the asset or participant? In some cases, you might want to update a field at a later stage. For those cases, should you always put in a dummy value at the start? Or wouldn't it be better that you just leave it blank at that time.

Comment: In the testing I did - missing fields generated errors as expected.  Obviously fields flagged Optional can be left blank.
If you have a concrete error that differs from mine, please add a comment to the issue